# Magento2: Change date format in order email and translate the months of the date

Tags: email, translate

[image] I want to translate the months of this date and also change date format. Could you give recommendations how to do that? (It's an order email)

Comment: To which language? And to what format?

Comment: Lithuanian, but better for Estonian also. The format right now 2024.year 27. febr. 10:34:33 -> need to be 27. veebruar 2024 10:34:33

Comment: You can use Mageplaza's Lithuanian and Estonian language packs which will do the required translation.

Comment: Ok, but how to change the date format?